# SQL Server 2008 Copy Database Wizard: Fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use the SQL Server 2008 Copy Database Wizard to copy a SQL Server 2008 database.  I am using the SQL Management Object method.  The database contains a full-text index.  I have set the 'Server - Properties - Advanced - Full-Text Upgrade Option' to Reset.  However, the copy fails with the following error:

```
ERROR : 
errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query "/* 
'==============================================..." 
failed with the following error: "Cannot use a CONTAINS or 
FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'Product' because 
it is not full-text indexed."
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can copy my database would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

although I haven't resolved the issue I was having earlier, I have tried and succeeded with an acceptable alternative approach - copy only backup and restore.

Here are some useful references to read:

Copying Databases with Backup and Restore:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx

Copy Only Backup for SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1772

Thanks to all those that stopped by to view and edit / re-format my question.

Kind Regards

Walter

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as well.  I was never able to use the Copy Database Wizard to copy the database.

I even removed and then re-added the full-text indexes and catalog.

Performing a backup, and then a restore to a new database (don't forget to manually change the filenames that SQL will restore to, or it will try to overwrite the existing database.) worked just fine.

In my case, I didn't even want the full-text catalog, so I didn't care if it didn't come across.

Comment: I just realized the previous post was quite old.  Looks like Microsoft hasn't fixed this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Copy Database wizard. I was unable to do a backup to my local machine since the server was on a hosted environment and did not have access. This doesn't set the Identity for tables though. My solution was:

1. Create the a new local database.
2. Use the Import wizard, right click on database. Tasks->Import Data
3. Use the Sql Server Native Client and set the Source and Destination. This will import the tables / data but will not import the indexes / constraints.
4. Use the scripts below to get the indexes / constraints and foreign key from your source and run them on your local database. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3443/script-all-primary-keys-unique-constraints-and-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database-using-tsql/